# JS - Turning string into array objects without spaces and commas

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, mapping

What is the best way to split a string into array objects? I would like the following string:

```
var str = "New York, California, Indiana"
```

to turn into the following array

```
var arr =  ["New York", "California", "Indiana"]
```

Please note: the string includes spaces and commas that I would like to disregard, but some spaces need to be retained (i.e. space between "New York"). What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: `str.split(', ')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split` with the split parameter as `', '` so it will split the strings with their space values:

```js
var str = 'New York, California, Indiana';
var arr = str.split(', ');
alert(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with a String Split

```
var str = "New York, California, Indiana"
var arr= str.split(",");
```